# The method findViewById() is undefined for the type Fragment02

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm getting an error when trying to create a `WebView` the way I always do, saying

> The method `findViewById()` is undefined for the type Frament02

How come? I've read that I could refer to a parent activity using that method but I'm not sure if any of my `Activities` or `Fragment`s is using it?

```
public class Fragment02 extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_02, container, false);


            WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_02, container, false);
WebView myWebView = (WebView)view. findViewById(R.id.webView1);
return view.
```

Inflate the layout. Use the view object to initialize views in `fragment_02.xml`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById%28int%29

Alternatively you can just `return View` in `onCreateView` and in `onActivityCreated` use `getView().findViewById()` to initialize views.

Answer (score 2):

try this way

```
@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_02, container, false);
 WebView myWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
 return v;
}
```

You should reference your `Views` from your `Fragment` inflated view.